# Cannot convert string to string[]

Tags: c#, text-files

I'm trying to read each line in the text file and create a folder for it.

```
{
    Console.Write("Enter Path: ");
    Linktopaths = Console.ReadLine();
    var informtations = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(Linktopaths);
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(informtations);
}
```

I have an error message,

> Cannot convert string to string[]

on the last word in the code (`informtations`)

Comment: `ReadAllLines` returns `string[]` (array of strings) while `CreateDirectory` expects a single `string`

Comment: What is it you are ultimately trying to achieve? Clearly explain.

Comment: For future reference, if you get an error message, please include the message itself - the more specific you are, the better the answers will be.

Answer (score 1):

[`ReadAllLines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx) returns `string[]` (array of strings) while [`CreateDirectory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.createdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx) expects a single `string`

depending on what it is you are trying to achieve you should extract a string from the array and pass that to the `CreateDirectory` method.

```
Console.Write("Enter Path: ");
Linktopaths = Console.ReadLine();
string[] informations = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(Linktopaths);
foreach (string path in informations) 
{
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
}
```